# Including a pdf into latex and reference it

Tags: elsarticle, ref

A friend recommended me to use `elsarticle` for a report, which I am currently doing. Now I need to add an external pdf which contains a figure. Adding the figure works fine, but I wonder if I can reference it in the text via `\ref` and create a link?

So in the text I would like to refer in the following way:

Figure 1 shows that...

Figure 1 should be a link (what I mean is to click on it takes you to the figure in the document) to an external pdf included in the document. Is that possible? As I mentioned I am using `elsarticle`, mostly clean in terms of other classes, but I would expect this problem to be the same independent of the class.

Any hints appreciated!

code:

```
documentclass[authoryear,11pt]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
Figure 1 shows...

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Figure1.pdf} % just use any PDF as a placeholder here 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the `\includegraphics` between `\begin{figure} --- \end{figure}` and add a caption with your `\label` you can reference afterwards `:)`

```
\documentclass[authoryear,11pt]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
Figure \ref{fig:document} shows\ldots

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Figure1.pdf} % 
\caption{\label{fig:document}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Off topic **note**: it is better to use `\ldots` than explicitly typing `...`.